# How to cache django views only for unauthenticated users?

Tags: django, django-cache

I'd like to cache certain views/pages for unauthenticated users but django [cache_page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) does not seem to have such option. So wonderin how best can I achieve this?

Comment: You could vary the cache if a user has a cookie?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers

Comment: @AdamBenzan yes, I've seen that but since not sure what's the difference between unauthenticated and authenticated cookies, I don't know how to use it.