# How to cache a view only for unauthenticated users?

Tags: django, django-cache

I have a view which I want to cache only for unauthenticated users.
The view should be something like this:

```
@cache_page_for_guests(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
```

I've looked at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf) but could not but could not find any hints about this.

Actually my question is exactly as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154730/how-to-cache-django-views-only-for-unauthenticated-users), which is unanswered, and I could not make sense of the comments.

So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom decorator like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

def cache_page_for_guests(cache_life_span):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return cache_page(cache_life_span, key_prefix="_auth_%s_" % not request.user.is_authenticated())(view_func)(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

Then in view

```
@cache_page_for_guests(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
```

Comment: I get syntax error in `return cache_page(cache_life_span, key_prefix="_auth_%s_" % not request.user.is_authenticated())(view_func)(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Try this `return cache_page(cache_life_span, key_prefix="_auth_%s_" % request.user.is_authenticated() is False)(
                view_func)(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Now I get `NameError: global name 'wraps' is not defined` error.

Comment: Import it like this `from django.utils.six import wraps`

Comment: Now I get `NameError: global name 'available_attrs' is not defined`

Comment: from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

Comment: The error is gone, but the decorator does not work correctly: It caches the page for authenticated user too. So I had to un-accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import wraps
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page


def cache_page_for_guests(*cache_args, **cache_kwargs):
    def inner_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                return cache_page(*cache_args, **cache_kwargs)(func)(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner_function
    return inner_decorator
```

you can use `cache_page_for_guest` just like `cache_page`. It'll accept the same arguments as of `cache_page`. Based on the user's authentication, it'll show either a normal view or a cached view.

```
@cache_page_for_guests(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
...
```