# How to use different views for a certain url base on authentication?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

When a request come for `/page-one` url, I'd like to use `view_a` if the user is authenticated and `view_b` for the guest visitors.

The code should be like this:

```
def dummy(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print 'authuser' 
        return view_a(request) 
    else: 
        print 'unauth user'
        return view_b(request)
```

How can I achieve this in django?

I've looked at the docs but could not find any relevant guides about this.

Comment: Replace this pseud-code with a wrapper-function. Which would be a generic/dummy view doing nothing but choosing the right view. Just wrap your code with a function. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is_authenticated`
Use this in views

```
if user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
else:
    return render(request, 'polls/another-detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

Comment: This is for different templates `inside` a view. My question is about using `different views`.

Comment: So what's the problem? `def generic_view(request): if user.is_authenticated: return specific_view(request) else: return another_view(request)` @qliq

Comment: @IvanStarostin, for performance purposes, I need to use separate views.

Comment: Take another look at my comment. There are three views. @qliq

Comment: @IvanStarostin I don't use generic views, please update your answer based on old-fashioned urls-views, as per my question.

Comment: This is the direct answer to your question. There are no "generic views" in term of Django framework.

Comment: Your whole question is based on a total misunderstanding if you think there is any "performance" difference in using separate views.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the matter is that I want to cache the view for unauthenticated users and I don't want it to interfere with the ux of registered users. I could not do that in a single view,  so I want to have a separate view for that.

Comment: You certainly *can* do that in a single view. In any case, Ivan has given you the answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, this is my last resort as there are a couple of questions here, where people could not cache based on authentication in a single view, so that would be great if you could answer them:  like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521102/how-to-cache-a-view-only-for-unauthenticated-users or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154730/how-to-cache-django-views-only-for-unauthenticated-users

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to different views (not just render different templates)

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

...

if user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('some_detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('another_detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
```

and in your urls you would have to 'name' the view

```
path('another_detail/<int:pk>/', views.another_detail, name='another_detail'),
```